# DateFormatter() with double type seconds swift

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I am trying to convert date time taken from server to local time.
I am using DateFormatter(), and after research in the web, the format
server is sending looks like: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss". However, the actual string
server is sending looks like: 2021-06-21T06:00:19.251588, where I guess seconds are given in detailed format. However, when I run it through the function to convert into local time, it return nil. Here is my code:

```
func utcToLocal(dateStr: String) -> String? {
    //dateStr is 2021-06-21T06:00:19.251588
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr) {
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yy.MM.dd"
    
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Is there any chance I am using wrong dateFormat?

Comment: If necessary, use `String`'s `components(separatedBy:)` to remove the decimal points.

Comment: that might work. I should check! I was curious if there is any automatic way of converting it.

Comment: These are fractional seconds, represented by `.S` -> `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`